# I created a GCP project using terraform but it doesn't appear in the project list. Why?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am following the tutorial at https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/managing-gcp-projects-with-terraform

Basically it boils down to creating a `terraform-admin` default project with the rights to be a `roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator`

```
$ gcloud organizations get-iam-policy $TF_VAR_org_id
bindings:
...snipped...
- members:
  - domain:raverun.com
  - serviceAccount:terraform@terraform-admin.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator
```

I am not going to duplicate the `project.tf` file here but the main items are:

```
provider "google" {
    ...snipped...
}

resource "google_project" "proj" {
    ...snipped...
    project_id      = "tf-foobar"
}

resource "google_project_services" "svcs" {
     ...snipped...
}
```

Before running `terraform apply`

```
$ gcloud projects list
PROJECT_ID          NAME              PROJECT_NUMBER
terraform-admin     terraform-admin     300000000000
```

After running `terraform apply`

```
$ terraform apply
...snipped...
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

project_id = tf-foobar

$ gcloud projects list
PROJECT_ID          NAME              PROJECT_NUMBER
terraform-admin     terraform-admin     300000000000
```

My question is why is the new project `tf-foobar` not showing up ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found the problem. I needed to give the domain owner's user account 
 `owner@mydomain.com` a project role that has the right to edit the newly created project. I tried this:

```
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "projiambinding1" {
  project = "${google_project.proj.project_id}"
  role    = "roles/editor"

  members = [
    "user:owner@mydomain.com",
    "serviceAccount:xxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    "serviceAccount:yyyyyyyyyyyyy@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com",
  ]
}
```

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?authuser=1&project=tf-foobar&organizationId=xxxxxxxxxxx

So now, my newly created project is now visible:

```
$ gcloud projects list
PROJECT_ID          NAME                   PROJECT_NUMBER
terraform-admin     terraform-admin        300000000000
tf-foobar           tf-foobar              111111111111
```